# CakePHP v3.0 beforeFilter correct syntax

Tags: php, cakephp, before-filter

I'm building a project using CakePHP v3.0. 
This is my original beforeFilter method inside a controller:

```
public function beforeFilter(Event $event)
    {
        parent::beforeFilter($event);
        $this->Auth->allow('add','logout','authorize');
    }
```

This worked until I installed the app on a different server and 'authorize' action stopped being accessible without authentication.
The only solution I found was putting the actions inside an array, like this:

```
public function beforeFilter(Event $event)
    {
        parent::beforeFilter($event);
        $this->Auth->allow(array('add','logout','authorize'));
    }
```

If I didn't misunderstood CakePHP 3 book the first case should work, shouldn't it?. 
What's the correct syntax for this situation?.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I kinda doubt that the first variant really worked, it was probably just luck, respectively another problem that made it possible to access your guarded `authorize()` action, as the `AuthComponent::allow()` method takes only a single argument, which is either the name of a single action, or an array of actions.

So, long story short, multiple actions must be passed as arrays.

See also

- **[Cookbook > Authentication > Making Actions Public](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#making-actions-public)**
- **[\Cake\Controller\Component\AuthComponent::allow()](http://api.cakephp.org/3.0/class-Cake.Controller.Component.AuthComponent.html#_allow)**

Comment: My bad. I didn't know that of PHP 5.4 you can also use the short array syntax. Thanks for your answer.